# jQuery post with serialize IE issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, serialization, post

```
var jqxhr = $.post(url, $("#saveShipAdrs").serialize(), function(response) {
      // set form values to view
      var fld;
      $('#editShipAdrs input[name*="Livraison"]').each(function(){ 
          fld = "#show"+$(this).attr("name");
          $(fld).html($(this).val());
      });
      // set success message
      $(".success").html("Shipping address updated");
    })
    .error(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
         $(".error").html("Shipping address cannot be updated");
         alert(xhr.status+"\n"+xhr.statusText+"\n"+thrownError);
    });
 });
```

Here "saveShipAdrs" is the id of the form.

This code works fine in FF but not in IE.
in IE it gives

```
xhr.status = 0
xhr.statusText = error
thrownError = Invalid Argument
```

I have tried for `serializeArray` and tried looking for other similar questions but didn't find the solution.

Comment: What returns $("#saveShipAdrs").serialize() in IE ?

Comment: it returns

ShipAdrsAjxRqst=1&NomLivraison=VALUE&PrenomLivraison=VALUE&AdresseLivraison=VALUE&CodePostalLivraison=VALUE&VilleLivraison=VALUE&TelephoneLivraison=VALUE&PaysLivraison=VALUE

(i.e. field=value pair)
in IE and FF both

Comment: The status 0 may stand for the fact, that the request is cancelled because of a different domain. What is url ?

Comment: working on localhost only. 
url: http://localhost/_project_/address.php

Comment: ok, you were right, the issue was because i kept the action attribute empty in form. fixed now, thank you. :)

Comment: @Dr.Molle: can you post your comment as answer, so that I can accept it :) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dr.Molle suggested, status 0 is returned when the request is cancelled because of a different domain.

Here the issue was, I kept the action attribute of form tag empty to submit on self ( action="" ).

Which doesn't mean that the domain is different but when I put the current page's URL in action attribute, the problem fixed.

If anybody wants to explain in detail that what was the exact issue for empty action, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery has the bug on IE 10 (Standard/Quirks Mode), that the .serialize() and .serizlizeArray() can not serialize form data.

```
<div id="showRole">
<form>
<input name="roleName" type="text" />
<input name="des" type="text" />
</form>
</div>
```

The fix is: var data = $("#showRole input").serialize(); use div's id to reference the form and serialize the data.

The IE just change the DOM tree and jquery can't get elements.